# How to set the y-axis to 0, if the screen is beyond the orginal screen or below the screen--In iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I am in the learning process ,I have this particular code, for whenever we click on the textfield or textview the screen moves up and when we resign the keyboard the screen gets to its original position its working fine for Both Landscape and Portrait Mode

What is the problem is. Initially it is in Portrait mode, When We click on the textfield or textview the screen is raising and the keyboard is shown, now when i rotate to landscape and resign the keyboard  the screen is getting downwards and the same is happening for the vice-versa.

```
    - (void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField textView:(UITextView *)textView up:(BOOL)up{   
            int animatedDistance;  
            int moveUpValue; 

            if (textField) {  
                moveUpValue = textField.frame.origin.y+ textField.frame.size.height;  
              }  
           else {  
                moveUpValue = textView.frame.origin.y+ textView.frame.size.height;   
             }  

            NSLog(@"moveup%d",moveUpValue);

            UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                 orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
              {
               if(textField){
                  animatedDistance = 216-(650-moveUpValue-5);
                }
               else{
                 animatedDistance = 216-(850-moveUpValue-5);
                }
              }
           else
             {
               if(textField){
                  animatedDistance = 162-(505-moveUpValue-5);
                }
               else{
                  animatedDistance = 162-(750-moveUpValue-5);
             }
         }
         NSLog(@"animated%d",animatedDistance);

        if(animatedDistance>0)
         {
           const int movementDistance = animatedDistance;
           const float movementDuration = 0.3f; 
           int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
           NSLog(@"movement portrait%d",movement);
           [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
           [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
           [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
           scrollview.frame = CGRectOffset(scrollview.frame, 0, movement);       
           [UIView commitAnimations];

         }
   }
```

I would like to now how can i solve this issue, or how can we change the y axis to 0.

Please Kindly do help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can use orientation delegate methods to update animatedDistance as per new orientation. so when you resign the keyboard then animatedDistance would be as per currentOrientation.

Comment: Please refer this link for your answer..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090063/how-to-manage-application-when-orientation-changes/8090119#8090119

Comment: I have already used that, and - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
       interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self portraitFrames];
    }
    else {
        [self landscapeFrames];
    }
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: In  portraitframes and landscapeframes method i have written the textfields frames.

Answer (score 1):

validate the animatedDistance settings when the device orientation changes.